# Request for new password when user login for the first time

Tags: users

I am using darland theme in drupal7 site and I want user to reset their password for the fist time when they login with temporary login credentials given by admin,i,e created user when he login for the first time he should able to see the reset password form and later he can use his account as required,!!how to resolve this issue??can anyone know?

And below screen shot which i have added is my login screen and the code showing up in the right page is cos i have added the code in page.tpl.php to solve above problem explained so now it looks like, however if i take off the code from page.tpl.php it will be removed.
[image]

[image]

Comment: This is the link for reset password `/user/pass`. By default reset password link is added below the user login block. You can add this link anywhere you want using menu.

Comment: @SumitMadan: thanks, i got it, but user should login with the password provided by admin after once they login for the first time it should ask to reset there password....just like gmail facility

Comment: @kashish as in your image there is a *login* link shown. Click on this link, there will you see *request new password* link under tab.

Comment: please can you show up your login form?

Comment: waqar Ali: please find the login page attached

Comment: @kashish Here is the module you can use : https://www.drupal.org/project/force_password_change.

Comment: thanks @Sumit...i am looking for the solution from long time, well i will try with this also. and update u

Answer (score 2):

## Options to set a password

First of all, the very only way for any user to change their password, is using either of these approaches:

- using `/user/xyz/edit` (with xyz = uid of the user), where there is an option to change your password. But: this can only be done for a logged in user (which assumes that the user succeeded in entering their (old) password).
- using a "one time login URL", as further described below.

## Requesting a new password

When you are not logged in, you can navigate to `/user/password` within your site (either for D6 or D7). That is where you will find the "request new password".

For a logged in user, in D7, who navigates to `/user/password`, you won't get the same "request new password" form however. Instead, you'll get something like so (`your.name@yourdomain.com` is the eMail Id to where the request new password eMail will be mailed to):

> Password reset instructions will be mailed to your.name@yourdomain.com. You must log out to use the password reset link in the e-mail.

## eMail a one time login URL

You may also want to look at what is configured as email templates when new users are created (located at `admin/config/people/accounts`). Such as the template for "a new user created by an administrator". By default (in D7) that template looks like so (bold markup added here):

> [user:name],
>
> A site administrator at [site:name] has created an account for you.
>   You may now log in by clicking this link or copying and pasting it to
>   your browser:
>
> [user:one-time-login-url]
>
> This link can only be used once to log in and **will lead you to a page
>   where you can set your password**.
>
> After setting your password, you will be able to log in at
>   [site:login-url] in the future using:
>
> username: [user:name] password: Your password

So this one time login URL could be used by a new user. And if for some reason that URL doesn't work (anymore), then such user can still user  `/user/password`.

**Variation**: any user (such as an admin ...) can use that URL and specify the eMail ID of the new user who has to set a new password (the eMail will arrive at the new user ... if the eMail ID is correct).

## Redirect on login when using a one-time login URL

One might consider adding links like `/user/password` and/or `/user/xyz/edit` (with xyz = uid of the logged in user) anywhere in your site (e.g. somewhere in your theme).

However, I'd use an approach using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module to redirect on login when using a one-time login and password reset. How to actually do so (there are multiple solutions) is detailed in [issue # 480584](https://www.drupal.org/node/480584). Personally I'd go for a solution based on what is described in [comment #37 of it](https://www.drupal.org/node/480584#comment-9626805).

If you're not familiar (enough/yet) with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), checkout the 32 (!!!) great, and free, video tutorials [Learn the Rules framework](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/learn-the-rules-framework), organized in 7 chapters.

## Use the Force password change module

Another approach might be to use the [Force password change](https://www.drupal.org/project/force_password_change) module (available also for D8 now, **merci [Jaypan](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/66659/jaypan)!**). Here are some details from its project page:

> This module allows administrators to force users, by role, individual user, or newly created user, to change their password on their next page load or login, and/or expire their passwords after a period of time.
>
> Features:
>
> - Ability to force all users in a role to change their password.
> - Ability to force individual users to reset their password from their profile edit page (user/[UID]/edit).
> - Ability to set an expiry on passwords so that if users haven't changed their password within that time period, they will be required to do so.
> - Ability to force all new users to change their password on first-time login (site-wide setting for all new users).
> - Ability for admins to force individual users to change their password on first time login when creating a new user. (Note: If the global setting forcing all new users to reset their password is enabled on the module settings page, this checkbox will not appear as it is redundant).
> - Listing of stats on the user edit page (user/[UID]/edit) showing:
>
>   - Whether the user has a pending forced password change.
>   - When the user last had their password forced to be changed.
>   - When the user last changed their password.
> - Status page for each role showing:
>
>   - Password change details by user.
>   - The last time at which the role was forced to change the password.
>   - A form to force the password change for all users in that role.

Use `admin/config/people/force_password_change`
and enable  `Force password change on first-time login` (can also be configured for selected roles).

Comment: OK, I "finished" my answer ... Curious to hear if you want to consider such "Rules" approach ... Are you familiar with Rules? If not: you don't know what you're missing ... PS: note that I cleaned up (=deleted) my prior comments also (you may want to do the same).

Comment: pierre Vriens: i am not so familiar with rules m newbie to drupal, well thanks a lot i will try as u have given the solution.):):):):

Comment: Thank you for the feedback for now. I added "some" more recommended tutorials to get you going with "rules". After you had some time to digest / study, you will hopefully not forget to provide some feedback to this (and the other?) answers to your question here. similar to what is written in http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers ...

Comment: Added another option (module) to consider, near the end of my answer ...

Comment: I just voted it up - partially because I'm the creator of the Force Password Change module that you wrote about in the post. It was made for this exact type of situation. I just recently ported it to D8, with a full set of tests, so the D8 version is the most stable one yet.

Comment: Thank you @Jaypan ! ... FYI: I integrated part of your comment in my answer also now.

Answer (score 0):

Check it to putting in theme file

```
function YOURTHEMENAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'user_pass':
        print '<pre>';print_r($form); print '</pre>';
      break; 
  }
}
```

Comment: adi:theme in which file...?m using danland

Comment: this is not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibility / ways.

1. Add css.

   ```
   #block-user-0 .item-list  { display: none;}
   ```
2. Show link in your module.

   `if(isset($tabs['#primary'][1]['#link']['path'])
   && 
   $tabs['#primary'][1]['#link']['path'] == 'user/password')
   { 
   show($tabs['#primary'][1]);
   }`

Hope this can solve your problem.

Comment: Viraj : please tell me where to add these 1 and 2 code which u have provided

Comment: Kashish : In page.tpl.php

Comment: #block-user-0 .item-list  { display: none;} this and 2nd one do we need to keep in page.tpl.php?? m in learning stage ....m sorry

Comment: viraj: after adding i am my login screen looks as above ...i have attached screen shot, please do check

Comment: For that, i need to go through what you did, Where you did. ?

Comment: css should be added in custom.css file.

Comment: i have added the if(isset($tabs['#primary'][1]['#link']['path'])
&& 
$tabs['#primary'][1]['#link']['path'] == 'user/password')
{ 
show($tabs['#primary'][1]);
} at line 33 in page.tpl.php file

Comment: Kashish : sorry, But i am unable to get the exact the exact idea what is your issue source. I need to go through whole code. Using stackexchange, I can't help you. If you can share your code file then I can do something.

Comment: thanks for trying to help me,but i am using danland theme for drupal7 http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/danland-7.x-1.0.zip and in that page.tpl.php file.

Comment: Ok kashish, I will go through it, And will let you know once i found solution.